# How to obtain command completion list

Tags: vim

I created unite source [cmdmatch](https://github.com/majkinetor/unite-cmdmatch) which lets you among other things fuzzy complete wildmenu items. I would like to find a better method to obtain the completion list (method I use is given [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_ex_command_line_completion_as_a_list) and is problematic because with large number of completion items screen will be filled up entirely [to see why just press `:<c-a>` if you didn't remap `<c-a>`])

The other solution would be to hide vim's cmd line completely while I am grabbing the list although I don't think that is possible in vim (or at least limit the amount of text it displays so it doesn't fill up screen). Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

First try has the same flickering problem although it looks like it works faster

```
fu! GetCompletion(input)
    call feedkeys(":" . a:input . "FF\<esc>\<cr>")
endf

cno FF <C-A><C-\>eg:Save()<CR>

fu! g:Save()
    let g:x = getcmdline()
endf
```

Result can be seen as:

`:call GetCompletion('help a')`
`:echo x`

**SOLUTION**

```
let g:cmdmatch = {}
fu! g:cmdmatch.set_c( base ) dict
    let self.c = a:base
endfu

fu! GetCommandCompletion( base )
    cno [MATCH] <c-a><c-\>eg:cmdmatch.set_c(getcmdline())<cr>
    sil! exe 'norm :' . a:base . '[MATCH]'
    cu [MATCH]
    retu g:unite_cmdmatch.c
endf
```

Test: `echo GetCommandCompletion("help '")`

Comment: Have you tried using `<C-\>e` and `getcmdline()`?  See `:help c_CTRL-\_e`.  As a proof of concept, I just tried `:cmap FF <C-A><C-\>e'XXX'.getcmdline().'YYY'<CR>`.

Comment: That is very and I think I will be able to use it. I will look more into it and post solution here if I succeed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately this method suffers from the same problems. See edited question.

Comment: The problem is that `<C-A>` fills up the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to execute the entire completion with `:silent`, so that the output won't actually happen (but completion is still magically done). The following function retrieves the completions already parsed into a List, by triggering the completion and then wrapping the output in `:return split('...')`. Of course, you can also `:return '...'` if you need a single string.

```
function! GetCommandCompletion( base )
    silent execute "normal! :" a:base . "\<C-a>')\<C-b>return split('\<CR>"
endfunction
```

#### demo

```
:let cmds = GetCommandCompletion('no')
:echo cmds
['noautocmd', 'nohlsearch', 'noreabbrev', 'noremap', 'noremenu', 'normal']
```

Comment: One little problem is that some long outputs like completion for `help a` have all sort of problematic chars like `'` or `"` but I guess `getcmdline()` will solve that.

Comment: Yes; if not, define a custom command `:Capture` that slurps in all arguments passed to it, and prepend that instead of `:return`.